# SQL query to find rows

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a table `mytable` in ORACLE database having only one column `Roll_no` like following:

```
Roll_no
----------
CD01 0001
CD01 0002
CD01 0004
CD01 0005
CD01 0008
```

here `CD01` is fixed, after `CD01` one space is there and then numbers are written `0001` and onwards.

Please see here that `CD01 0003`, `CD01 0006`, `CD01 0007` are missing and these are my required output.

Required output:

```
Roll_no
----------
CD01 0003
CD01 0006
CD01 0007
```

How can I write a SQL query to find out these missing alphanumeric characters? Any ideas please

Comment: since the values in your fields are not atomic (which is not a good idea by the way), i doubt you can achieve what you want with one SQL query

Comment: can you please tell me that sql query, i am trying but it is not displaying the required output

Comment: @marc_s...any idea please how can i get the desired output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could generate the full list of number and then with a NOT EXISTS (or NOT IN) filter the existing records out. For example:

```
SELECT new_roll_no
  FROM (SELECT 'CD01 ' || to_char(rownum, 'fm0000') new_roll_no FROM dual 
        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (SELECT to_number(MAX(substr(roll_no, 6))) FROM T))
 WHERE new_roll_no NOT IN (SELECT roll_no FROM T)
 ORDER BY 1
```

Here's how it works:

- CONNECT BY LEVEL is a bit of a trick query, it will generate rows up to the level you indicate (in this case I chose the max from your table). I think this query first appeared on the [askTom](http://asktom.oracle.com) site and is now quite widespread.
- I've generated 8 rows, I will next use the TO_CHAR function to make a column look like your primary key (see the [format model](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF51073) documentation of the [TO_CHAR](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions201.htm#i79330) function).
- I then compare these generated values to your actual table value (NOT IN is an ANTI-JOIN)

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer but when i run the query it is telling `ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis`

Comment: @saroj: I was missing a parenthesis, it should work now (I still get an error on 9ir2 but it works in 11gr2)

Comment: thanks a lot...it worked, just one request to explain briefly what are these terms: `fm0000`, `connect by level` `new_roll_no` ? please explain little bit

Answer (score 1):

```
select n
  from (select 'CD01' || to_char(rownum, '0009') n
          from dual
    connect by level <= (select max(substr(roll_no, 6)) from mytable))
where n not in (select roll_no from mytable)
```

Comment: Apologies, didn't see Vincent post.